# sql - How to select two different counts from different level of join?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am not sure the title is correct for my problem and I'd better to give an example.

I have three tables: `Publication`, `Journal`, `Published`. Their columns are like followings:

```
    **Publication table**

       pub_id,     journal_id

    **Journal table**

       journal_id,   article_id

    **Published table**

       article_id
```

So if I do

```
    select pub.pub_id, count(j.article_id) 

    from publication pub

    inner join journal j on pub.journal_id=j.journal_id

    group by pub.pub_id
```

I get the `total number of articles` of a journal which need to be published for each `pub_id`, right?

If I do

```
    select pub.pub_id, count(p.article_id) 

    from publication pub

    inner join journal j on pub.journal_id=j.journal_id

    inner join published p on j.article_id=p.article_id

    group by pub.pub_id
```

I get the `total number of published articles` of a journal which need to be published for each `pub_id`, right?

so through the above two queries, I can get `the number of articles that need to be published` and `the number of articles that have been published`.

My question is that how to write a single query to get these two numbers at the same time?

I need to show these two number in the same table.

P.S: I am using Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
select pub.pub_id, count(p.article_id), count(distinct j.article_id) 
from publication pub
inner join journal j on pub.journal_id=j.journal_id
left join published p on j.article_id=p.article_id
group by pub.pub_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `count(distinct ...)` to count journals only once, despite the extra rows added by adding a `join`.  That allows you to `left join` the `published` table:

```
select pub.pub_id, count(distinct j.journal_id), count(p.article_id)
from publication pub
inner join journal j on pub.journal_id=j.journal_id
left join published p on j.article_id=p.article_id
group by pub.pub_id
```

Comment: Yes, it works. thanks for your answer. but I will mark @podiluska answer  as his came earlier. ok?

Comment: @Jackson. These two queries are different, unless you only have one article per journal.

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi no, I have a number of articles per journal. what do you mean by `different`.

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi: only difference is the order of the columns, both do `count(distinct ...)` on the `journal` table

Comment: @Andomar I'm counting articles, you're counting journals.

Comment: @podiluska: I think counting `journal_id` is safer, since an unpublished article might have a `journal_id`, but not yet an `article_id` which seems to be the foreign key to the `published` table.

Comment: @Andomar Perhaps. I was assuming that the article_id was the primary key of the article :)